# Verb tense in academic writing

Tags: verbs, tenses

Consider this sentence.

- X studied fault structure using method A. Y studied fault structure
  using method B. However, the geometrical complexity of a fault
  remained poorly understood.

Do I have to use 'remains poorly understood' or 'remained poorly understood'?

Comment: Is it *still,* in the present, poorly understood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to say.

If you use the past tense, it will be understood as referring to the time immediately after both studies. In other words, neither study provided a clear understanding of fault structure. However, it's possible that some later work may have solved this.

If you use the present tense, it means that it's still not understood. In isolation it suggests that there hasn't been any further work on it since then, as singling out X and Y's work implies that they're the only attempts.

Comment: I so want to upvote your ever-clear answers if not for the fact that past already means then and present means now, probably in all languages. So ...